# get a percentage of a file

Tags: text-processing, command-line

Is there a linux command to return the last x % of a file? I know tail can return a number of lines (-n) or number of bytes (-c), but what if I wanted to get the last 25% of a file? Is there a command to do that?

Comment: No, but you can use `wc` to get a line/char count of the whole file, perform your own calculation, then pass the resulting value to `tail`

Comment: If you just want to *view* the last x %, then you could use `less` with a per-cent offset e.g.`less +p75 somefile`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

GNU split can do pretty much what you ask; given a text file `in.txt`, this will print the last quarter (part 4 out of 4) in terms of number of bytes (not lines), without splitting lines:

```
split -n l/4/4 in.txt
```

Here is the relevant documentation for `split -n CHUNKS`:

> `CHUNKS` may be: [...] `l/K/N` output Kth of N to stdout without
>   splitting lines

In the very specific case mentioned as an example in the question,
`4/4` requests the fourth quarter, or the last 25% of the input
file. For sizes that are not 1/n of the input, I do not think split
provides such a straightforward solution.

Answer (score 6):

Complex **`bash`** + **`stat`** + **`bc`** + **`tail`** solution for any percentage:

```
get_last_chunk () { 
    local p=$(bc <<<"scale=2; $1/100")
    tail -c $(printf "%.0f" $(echo "$(stat -c%s $2) * $p" | bc)) "$2"
}
```

---

- `$1` and `$2` - are the function's 1st and 2nd arguments respectively
- `p` - variable assigned with percentage value as float number (for ex. `0.14` or `0.55`)
- `stat -c%s $2` - getting the actual size of the input file in bytes
- `tail -c N $2` - getting the last `N` bytes of the file

---

Or use the more simplified version:

```
get_last_chunk () { 
    tail -c "$(($(stat -c%s - < "$2") * $1 / 100))" < "$2"))"
}
```

*Signature*: `get_last_chunk <percent> <filename>`

Sample `file.txt`:

```
apples
oranges
bananas
cherries
```

---

Test cases:

```
get_last_chunk 17 file.txt
ries
```

---

```
get_last_chunk 77 file.txt
oranges
bananas
cherries
```

---

```
get_last_chunk 29 file.txt
cherries
```

Comment: I like the creativity of this one. :)

Comment: You are probably better using `stat -c%s filename.txt` to get the filesize, rather than wc. `stat` will call fstat (or similar) to ask the fs driver for the filesize, rather than scanning the whole file.

Comment: `echo {{expression}} | bc` is a useless use of `echo`. We can instead `bc <<< {{expression}}`.

Comment: @user137369, `<<<` means creating a temporary files filling it with the text, make that the stdin of the command and delete it. Whether it's better or worse than using the builtin `echo` with a pipe is up for debate. That also adds a requirement on the system having a zsh-like shell. But here, you don't use `bc` (nor `printf`) at all, you can use shell arithmetic expression.

Comment: That assumes the GNU implementation of `stat`. Also note that for symlinks, that gives the size of the symlink instead of that of the file it points to. You'd need the `-L` option. You also forgot the `--` and the quotes around the parameter expansions and command substitutions. Even with those added, that would still not work for a file called `-`. Best would be to use the standard `wc -c < "$2"` here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, so you think that "rollback" is reasonable as my initial approach is more portable and preferable?

Comment: Sorry I meant "don't _need_", not "don't _use_" above. Just `tail -c "$(($(stat -c%s - < "$2") * $1 / 100))" < "$2"))"` would address most of my comments.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, ok, added as simplified version. Thanks.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You’re thinking of `<`. `<<<` ([*here string*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html)) doesn’t require creating any file; it can be substituted just like in my example. It also does not require a zsh-like shell; it works perfectly fine in bash.

Comment: @user137369, [here documents and here strings in `bash` are implemented with deleted temporary files](/a/181996) like they were in the Bourne shell (which didn't have herestrings, just heredocs, herestrings come from zsh, so bash is a zsh-like shell in that regard)

Answer (score 0):

To get the last `$1`% in terms of number of *lines*, portably (POSIXly):

```
last_percent() (
  percent=${1?}; shift
  ret=0
  for file do
    lines=$(wc -l < "$file") &&
      tail -n "$((lines * percent / 100))" < "$file" || ret=$?
  done
  exit "$ret"
)
```

Example:

```
$ seq 12 > a; printf '%s\n' aaaaaa bbbbb cccc dd > b
$ last_percent 25 a b
10
11
12
dd
```

For the last `$1`% in terms of number of *bytes*, replace `wc -l` with `wc -c` and `tail -n` with `tail -c`. Beware though that the first output line would likely be partial. On the same files as above, that would give:

```
$ last_percent 25 a b
11
12
c
dd
```

With ksh93, you could write it with only builtins and not a single fork as:

```
last_percent() (
  percent=$1; shift
  ret=0
  for file do
    command /opt/ast/bin/cat < "$file" <#((EOF*(100-percent)/100)) || ret=$?
  done
  exit "$ret"
)
```

Using its `<#((...))` seeking operator.

The same with `zsh` (except that `cat` is not builtin there):

```
zmodload zsh/system zsh/stat
last_percent() {
  local percent=$1 ret=0 file n
  shift
  for file do
    {
      sysseek -w end 0 &&
        sysseek -w end ' - systell(0) * percent / 100' &&
        cat
    } < $file || ret=$?
  done
  return $ret
}
```